# Why does isNAN("12") evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript

Why does JavaScript interpret 12 and "12" as equal?

```js
function sanitise(x) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  return x;
}

var a = "12"
var b = 12
console.log(typeof(a))
console.log(sanitise(a));
console.log(sanitise(b));
```

Output:

```
> "string"
> "12"
> 12
```

And then, what is the difference between "12" and "string"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: I'm upvoting this question. Because ,There's a war down there for "downvote" :).

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL There are only 2 downvotes as of now. :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why “12” is a not NaN in JavaSciprt?

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isnan-number), there is an implicit conversion ***toNumber*** before checking if the given input is a *number* or not (or **Not a Number** - **`NaN`** )

> 1. Let num be ToNumber(number).

So `isNaN("12")` => `isNaN(12)` => **false**

Comment: `isNaN` checks if the value is `NaN`, not if it's not a number type.

Comment: @MichaelMior *not if it's not a number type* Where did I say that it is checking the number type?

Comment: @Thilo Yes of course `isNaN` check **if not a number**, is there is a difference between check for number and checking for number type?

Comment: @Thilo Then why is `isNaN( "s" )` true? You are overthinking this - As per spec, it it invokes `toNumber` method and then checks if the output is a number or not!

Comment: "before checking if the given input is a number or not"

Comment: `isNaN` does not check if the output is a number, it checks if the value (after calling `toNumber` is the *value* `NaN`. The output is equivalent in the cases I can think of, but the mechanism is different.

Comment: @michaelmior why is `isNaN("s")` true? I just don't understand why everyone here is over thinking this.

Comment: `isNaN("s")` is true because `ToNumber(s)` results in the value `NaN`.

Comment: @michaelmior which is precisely what I have mentioned in my answer. toNumber is an internal method which is invoked just so that isNaN can tell whether the passed input is a number or not.

Comment: But `isNan` does *not* check if the output of `ToNumber` is a number, it checks if it is the value `NaN`.

Comment: @MichaelMior But you don't pass `NaN` to the `isNaN`, you passed `'s'`. And `s == NaN` is **false**.  So what does `isNaN` do again? And `NaN` is also denotes **Not a Number**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Answer (score 7):

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not.

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), NaN values are generated when arithmetic operations result in undefined or unrepresentable values. Such values do not necessarily represent overflow conditions. A NaN also results from attempted coercion to numeric values of non-numeric values for which no primitive numeric value is available.

For example, dividing zero by zero results in a NaN — but dividing other numbers by zero does not.

Here "12" is not a number but it is not `NaN` either. Therefore `isNaN()` returns `false`.

*Also, when the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a `Number`. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`.*

Therefore `isNaN('s')` returns true as 's' is converted to a number. Parsing this as a number fails and returns `NaN`.

Comment: In this case why is `isNaN( "s" )` true?

Answer (score 1):

It's because behind the scene, isNaN converts the argument passed to it to number before checking if it's a number

Comment: `isNaN` checks if the value is `NaN`, not if it's not a number type.

Comment: @MichaelMior You just musunderstand the answer

Comment: Perhaps. I think the answer is incomplete though without explaining the meaning of `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

> Was JavaScript takes "12 and 12 as same things?

It doesn't.

Under **some** conditions, it will implicitly convert `12` to `"12"` or vice versa (other examples include if you are doing a comparison with `==` or concatenating a string with `12` (`"" + 12`).

> And then, what is the difference between "12" and "string"?

One is a string representing the number twelve as digits, the other is a string representing the word string.

The `typeof` operator tells you (in the form of a string) what type of data a value is.

Comment: @Rajesh — I didn't claim otherwise in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the info below.

> This function is different from the Number specific Number.isNaN()
>   method.
>
> The global isNaN() function, converts the tested value to a Number,
>   then tests it.

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Comment: Having both these functions is confusing... Yea, loosely typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

`"12"` and `12` are not the same thing but in some contexts JS silently converts one to another.

For example, `"12" + 12` is `"1212"` (converts the number to string) but `"12" * 12` is `144` (converts the string to number).

The first conversion happens because `+` is used for both [numbers addition and strings concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). If one of its operands is a string then it makes sure the other is also a string (converts it to string if it is not already a string). In order to work as the addition operator, both its operands must be numbers.

On the other hand, the `*` is used only as the [multiplication operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Multiplication) and that's why it converts its operands to numbers in order to be able to work with them.

The [`isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) checks if its argument has the special floating-point value [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) that cannot be compared against other numbers using the usual [comparison operators (`==` and `===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). It doesn't check the type of its argument; its purpose **is not** to tell apart numbers from other types. It is used to detect  division by zero and values that cannot be represented by the floating-point number format (overflowing results on addition of large numbers, underflowing results on division of small values by large values etc.)